# $\frac{n^n}{e^{n^2}}$ converges or diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I wonder whether $\frac{n^n}{e^{n^2}}$ converges to $0$ or not when $n \to \infty$. And if yes, how I can show it.

Thank you.

Comment: hint $n^2>>n \log[n]$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $e^{n^2}=(e^n)^n$. Now, how do $n$ and $e^n$ compare as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a logarithm we have $n^2 - n \log n$, which clearly diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: Additionally,$$\log\left(\frac{n^n}{e^{n^2}}\right)=n\log n-n^2\to-\infty\implies \frac{n^n}{e^{n^2}}\to 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Adding to other answers, it suffices to show $n^2 / (n \log n) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Canceling the one power of $n$, all you need at that point is L'Hopital's rule to finish. Or you can show $e^n / n \to \infty$. Again, L'Hopital's rule makes this easy.